# Get "highest" character in C

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

I've tried to write a program which gets the highest character a person has entered. I made a program which gets the highest number work without any problem but with characters it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char characters[5];
    char highest = "a";

    printf("Please enter five characters: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i+=1) {
        scanf("%c", characters[i]);
    }

    printf("These are the characters you entered: ");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i+=1) {
        printf("%c  ", characters[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i+=1) {
        if (characters[i] > highest) {
            highest = characters[i];
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe highest character is %c", highest);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `char highest = "a";` actually compile?

Comment: Well, on Xcode (Macintosh) it does compile. Why "a", not 'a'?

Comment: Yes, because you're assigning a `String` to a `char` variable

Comment: @S.Eberl Please don't tag C questions as C++.

Comment: 'A' is less than 'a' so if caps are used it won't work. Initialize highest to 0

Comment: If it "doesn't work" then the obvious solution is to make it work. If you want a better answer than that, tell us specifically what isn't working what errors you get etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to convert a string literal `"a"` to a `char`. You should use a character literal.

```
char highest = "a";
//should be
char highest = 'a';
```

Additionally, `scanf` requires a pointer to store the result of the read.

```
scanf("%c", characters[i]);
//should be
scanf("%c", &characters[i]);
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/965aee4fb5b40959)

Comment: That solves the problem, thanks! Now, another problem occurs. It only read three instead of five characters on my Mac. The Live Demo instead works perfectly fine.

Comment: What to do about that?

Comment: Don't enter whitespace.

Comment: And if I 'want' to enter whitespace?

Comment: You could add a space into your format string: `" %c"`. This is a different question though.

Answer (score 3):

`char highest = "a";` is incorrect, it should be `char highest = 'a';` to compile.

Comment: On Xcode (Mac OS X) it compiles both ways. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

Character literals are specified with single quotes, not double quotes.  So this:

```
char highest = "a";
```

Should be:

```
char highest = 'a';
```

Also, the `%c` format specifier to `scanf` expects a pointer to `char`, but you're passing it a `char`.

So this:

```
scanf("%c", characters[i]);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%c", &characters[i]);
```

That should address your issues.

Comment: All parameters to functions are passed by value.  If you just pass in a `char`, then `scanf` won't be able to modify it.  By passing the address of that `char`, `scanf` can dereference the pointer and modify the memory location it points to, namely the array element in the calling function.

Answer (score -1):

There is another potential problem that hasn't been addressed. In C, it is guaranteed that the characters representing *digits* ('0', '1', ..., '9') are in order, but there is no such guarantee that the *letters* ('a', 'b', ...) are in any specific order.

Comment: ASCII for 'a' is smaller than 'b' or 'c'. Isn't that enough (if you forget about the case sensitive problem)?

Comment: Using EBCDIC, note that 'J'+1 is not equal to 'K'  ('K' is 'J'+6)

Comment: Why is that important for me? Mac OS X uses ASCII, too.